# Sharepoint: Error from token exchange: Runtime call was blocked because connection has error status

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, powerapps, power-automate

I created one flow when any sharepoint list items add or modified then I trigger on power automate flow, but sometimes its giving me the unauthorize error and flow is not trigger successfully. I got the below error from "Flow Checker" in Power Automate.

**Error from token exchange: Runtime call was blocked because connection has error status: Enabled| Error, and sharepointonline is in the block list. Connection errors: [ParameterName: token, Error: Code: Unauthorized, Message: 'Failed to refresh access token for service: sharepointonlinecertificatev2. Correlation Id=b432bd04-0487-4654-ad92-5bf4fc02968a, UTC TimeStamp=5/13/2021 4:45:42 PM, Error: Failed to acquire token from AAD: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS50173: The provided grant has expired due to it being revoked, a fresh auth token is needed. The user might have changed or reset their password. The grant was issued on '2021-05-12T06:23:56.0000000Z' and the TokensValidFrom date (before which tokens are not valid) for this user is '2021-05-12T22:00:06.0000000Z'.\r\nTrace ID: 271904ff-f200-4ab3-8cd3-e86d01532400\r\nCorrelation ID: e92855d2-cc58-42f1-9685-b152d0011481\r\nTimestamp: 2021-05-13 16:45:42Z","error_codes":[50173],"timestamp":"2021-05-13 16:45:42Z","trace_id":"271904ff-f200-4ab3-8cd3-e86d01532400","correlation_id":"e92855d2-cc58-42f1-9685-b152d0011481","error_uri":"https://login.windows.net/error?code=50173"}']**

Comment: There may be a small possibility the SharePoint connector is blocked. Did you already check your Data Loss Policies? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/wp-data-loss-prevention)

Comment: I have Multi Factor Authentication (MFA) so is that one reason to authenticate after some periods of time. That session is expire and going to established new session ?

Comment: Yes, that's definitely a possibility. If your company uses Privileged Identity Management your authorization can run out of time.

Comment: Is there any way to continue that MFA and also Power Automate authenticate successfully? Or need to setup anything on Azure AD or Power Automate?

Comment: At my company we use a user account in the Azure AD without MFA that acts as a Service Account for these scenarios.